# How to get all the partition keys in a SSTable?

Tags: cassandra

I'm doing some work on the Cassandra 3.11 source code, and I'm a bit confused by how SSTables are accessed. So far I've found three classes that all seem to be doing some reads on the SSTables: SSTableReader, Tracker, and View.

As for my problem, I'm looking to get a list of all the partition keys for each SSTable. My final aim is to find all the partition keys that exist in more than three SSTables at the same time. However, none of the three classes above, seem to contain the kind of method I have in mind ("getAllPartitionKeys()" or something similar). With this in mind, which class (or process) can give me this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a class called KeyIterator that can provide an Iterable of all the partition keys in a table. To use it do the following:

```
KeyIterator keyIterator = new KeyIterator(ssTableReader.descriptor, cfs.metadata());
```